# How to Convert a C# Dictionary in the code to a Powershell object?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0

Can any one help me? I have C# code that builds a dictionary and I need to convert that dictionary into PowerShell object. The object will then be pass it to a PowerShell script. 
 

My Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
```

Comment: Why do you need a conversion? PowerShell can work with dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current versions (v3/v4) should be able to use the Dictionary directly but I don't remember how well v2 handled generics.  Anyway, here is some pseudo-code (not guaranteed to compile) to convert to a hashtable of hashtables:

```
var hashtable = new Hashtable();
foreach (var kvPair in dict) {
    var hashtableInner = new Hashtable();
    foreach (var kvPairInner in kvPair.Value) {
        hashtableInner.Add(kvPairInner.Key, kvPairInner.Value);
    }

    hashtable.Add(kvPair.Key, hashtableInner);
}

# Pass hashtable to PowerShell as even v2 understands .NET hashtables
```